# How to auto update formula when a new column is added

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a body of data, and on another sheet I have calculations for the minimum and maximums of entire rows.

The data starts in D4 and each row is another data set. The problem is when I add a new column for new data, Excel does not update the formulas to automatically extend the range. I have to manually go through each error message and "Update to include cells".

Formula example:

```
=MIN(Historian!$D4:$AR4)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU.  Could you edit your post to include a screenshot of the error message you're receiving and perhaps some sample data?

Comment: The most easiest I would like to suggest,, create `Dynamic Named Range` ,,, then after as soon U  enter New Data, Excel allow the formula to workout with New data & your formula work as expected .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean that you begin using a column to the right of your earlier columns, "AS" in your formula's case because inserting on IN your range would achieve what you want.

There are several traditional approaches:

1. You can use what one internet site calls the "gray bar" approach. This is maybe the oldest idea (of ideas to systematically solve it... see #5 for probably the oldest idea). You have an empty column (in your case, but say "row" if up and down instead) to the left of your formula cells, and one to the right of them. So if you want to sum, say, a range like `D4:AR4` you'd use the range `C4:AS4` and always INSERT a column at the right, not just start using column AS. That would make Excel adjust your formula for you. The only real downside, usually, is it feels ancient and kludgy. Works like a dream though.
2. Use a formula that produces a `dynamic` range. This is a range that automatically expands when you begin using a row or column more. How? Well, that's the rub, eh? You have to find some clever way of telling Excel how to realize this. In practice, that is usually not something super-cleverness is needed for, but it can led to hard to notice mistakes. I might also mention that when you have little experience with Excel's functions, you might not even imagine the way some function can be shanghai'ed into doing this for you. But there are a ton of sites that give you a lot of ideas here and it's very easy, really, while being a fine set of lessons advancing you in Excel.
3. Use the above idea, but apply the formula to a Named Range. Like Rajesh S suggests. Some difficulties arise, of course. Once you figure up a good way to do it for each row, you can then begin creating each Named Range you need... you have 42,000 rows? Well, get started creating those 42,000 Named Ranges now then, 'cause they won't create themselves... But learning, and many sites that want to impart it, is on your side and you can alter your dynamic range making formula to base the cell addresses it uses on either the row (or column) it is in, or on its cell's relative location versus the source data, or both, and some other ideas too. You have a second layer of "dynamic" that you apply to the formula, and then you just need a single Named Range for all those cells if you can see a way to relate it reliably to where the formula you do your summing, or whatever in. This is also available on a ton of sites and is kind of easy, once you get the right mindset.
4. Use VBA. VBA is the gold standard for many things and is a gold mine for easily characterized, repetitive stuff. Simple things are not really hard to learn since you can usually do them with the macro recorder, then look at the VBA produced and go "A-Ha!" and just extend it as needed. And while VBA is not usually FREE-ly taught on the internet, you can still find a lot of the simpler things. VBA DOES take time to "do its thing" but it simply doesn't care if you have it examine 1,000 cells in the row, toss out all the blanks, and find a minimum for the cells with actual entries. And there are other simple ways to ignore those unused cells at the right in each row. On that scale, the time to do its thing doesn't add up to what it used to on modern computers. There are no "don't sort the database until leaving at 5pm" ('cause it will take 4-10 hours to sort) rules anymore because computers are FAST. (Also, using some VBA might take you over the hump, so to speak, and let you be willing to learn more of it instead of leaving that dreaded moment for "someday"... just a thought.)
5. Easiest of all, if it wouldn't cause other problems:  Just write the formula to include, say, 50 extra columns. Or 52:  `D4:CR4` and once a year or whatever, re-visit that and extend them more if you add lots of columns, or once a decade, if you don't add them so fast.